# Achievement icon doesn't display reputation changes

Tags: bug, reputation, android-app, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The achievement icon doesn't change color or show a number to inform the user of reputation changes.

I ran instances on two separate devices during the same period of time (the last few hours), one with settings > notifications enabled, one disabled. Neither one displayed any change in the icon, though I had three positive (and zero negative) reputation change events. When actually opening the dialog, events are correctly displayed. The phone with notifications enabled did not receive any android system notifications either (push notifications are enabled and functioning on it).

I was not interacting with the site in any other way during this time, so the notifications would not have been dismissed from outside the app.

Notifications-on device:
Samsung Galaxy S3, ATT version
Android 4.4.2
Running slimkat 4.4.2.build.4.1.Official

Notifications-off device:
HTC One E8, Hong Kong version
Android 5.0.2
Stock

Both devices are rooted and running the latest version of the SE app, and are logged in to the same account (this one).

Comment: For what it's worth, I am also seeing this (no icon change, no push notifications) on my non-rooted DROID MAXX with Android 4.4.4 with notifications enabled.

Comment: For what it's worth, the app *never* has this feature in the first place; there's no realtime visual indicator for reputation change, only inbox (and that's for a message, not a reputation change). Consider changing it to [tag:feature-request] if you want.