# Mobile app Facebook sign-in is broken - links to an old guest account

Tags: bug, android-app, user-accounts, facebook

Version: 1.0.77

On the sign-in screen it will show the Facebook button with my email address listed underneath it.  I click sign-in and it logs me in just fine but years ago I had answered a question using that same email address as a guest so it seems to log me into that guest account instead of the FB account where I have all my reputation.

Comment: I feel your pain, really. But you can work around this by creating new login, using Stack Exchange OpenID, then you will be able to login via the app.

Comment: Oops, my bad - you can add new login, but not Stack Exchange. If you care to create new gmail account just for this, you can go [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current), click "add more logins…" and add that new gmail account as your new login. Then you can use this to sign in via the app, and get the shiny hat. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you! I can login and it links to my account.  Add it as an answer if you want that sweet sweet rep.  I've found two issues on the app by doing this: it doesn't display my rep count in the top right corner (displays a zero), and it doesn't show my StackOverflow profile photo. sigh but good enough!

Comment: Cheers @Clay, will add shortly. As for the bugs, first is a well known issue (will try to find the report) and second is because you have Gravatar in SO, if you'll change your picture it will most likely appear in the app as well.

Comment: Huh? What badges?? Anyway, as promised: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258578/achievement-icon-doesnt-display-reputation-changes is the report.

Comment: critic badge and excavator I think - I had 16 before all this happened.  And it reset my profile photo, I hadn't checked the web.. and it just gave me the yearling badge even though I don't think I had posted anything with that email address.. I don't know.. terrible bug.

Comment: Whoops, didn't know adding a login is causing such side effects. Hopefully those badges will be back, and as for Yearling, you got 3 at once since you earned 600 in one year - bit tricky but no bug there.

Comment: It looks like it is recalculating all the badges (slowly) now that it is merged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/959/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-clayton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can simply add a new login and use this to sign in via the app.

To add such a login, e.g. using Google, follow those steps:

1. Make sure you have Google (gmail) account, or create a new one.
2. Go [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) and click "add more logins…".
3. Click "Google" button and login via  Google if required, confirming the new account.
4. Profit.

Now in the app, you can login using that account.

Comment: Ultimately it looks like it does not appear that it recalculated all my hats and it continues to error when clicking to wear a different hat.  My SO profile won't allow me to wear a hat.  It appears that I can still receive new hats though... so strange.

Comment: And it never re-gave me the 'Tag Editor' badge although I did edit a tag on a post last night to see if it would re-give it to me... interesting.

Comment: Time for a bug report, make sure to put all the details. :-)

Comment: Perhaps.  I'm unimpressed with their bug handling process.  More than a week with no response haha

Comment: @Clayton well, most bugs go without response for years. I learned long ago not to expect, and this way not getting disappointed (too much) - all in all, we should be happy with what we got. ;)

Comment: Now I'm even more unimpressed 

Comment: Well, you got most of the things back... and can use the app... :)