# My winter hats don't work "An error occurred while changing the hat" on StackOverflow.com

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015

The error that appears in a little red box:

```
An error occurred while changing the hat
```

My winter hats broke after I added an account that had an old question linked to it.  During the merge process it recalculated most (but not all) of  my badges and most (but not all) of my winter hats.  Since then I have been unable to wear a hat.  I just got the Odin hat and I'd love to wear it.  It shows a hat for me on MSE but  on StackOverflow.com it does not... and in either case, I am unable to wear it (or any other hat) and will receive an error.

Here is the original thread where I figure out how to add another account that subsequently broke winter hats for me:

[Mobile app Facebook sign-in is broken - links to an old guest account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270750/mobile-app-facebook-sign-in-is-broken-links-to-an-old-guest-account)

[image: sad odin]

Comment: All hats? Wow... thought you mean only one or two hats that you lost during the merge. Why didn't you report it before? Anyway, hope it's not too late, only few days until it's all over.

Comment: Yes, it occurs for or any and all hats.  SO didn't respond to my other bug report with broken login... was not optimistic that they would respond to another bug report.

Comment: Well, those are totally different bugs. The android app gets zero attention these days, but winter bash is something else. It used to get ultra fast attention in the beginning, though not sure if now balpa (the developer of the whole winterbash code) will bother to fix when it's ending in few days

Comment: Well, balpa, if you're out there it would be nice if you fix it 

Comment: This could be related: when in the chat room and you click for my profile "user profile on stackoverflow.com" it will go to a 404 page.

Comment: Yeah, chat got its own profile, many times the parent user is not being synchronized at all. Want a solid proof? See [this one](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/normal-human), he's very active on chat yet got no account in MSE, at all.

Comment: has it been reported as a bug before?

Comment: Yeah, think so, but it's not that important.

Comment: I can't find it... going to post it anyway