# Changing hats: "An error occurred while changing the hat - please try again"

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016

Every time I try to change hats, I get an error message. This started happening after I got my account merged with old account; prior to that hats worked fine for me.

This is probably the same problems as this issue from 2015: [My winter hats don't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272075/my-winter-hats-dont-work-an-error-occurred-while-changing-the-hat-on-stackove), which was closed as non-reproducible.

Comment: Anything logged in the browser console?  What browsers does this error occur on?

Comment: Console shows "jquery.min.js:4 POST http://meta.stackexchange.com/winter-bash/wear 400 (Bad Request)". This happens on Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) and Firefox 50.0.1 on macOS 10.12.2. Changing hats also fails when I use my Android phone and access the stackexchange website from Chrome.